# Windows: exceptions not handled in main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

Is it possible in windows to ignore exceptions not handled in main thread?

I understand that the OS would like to stop a process with an unhandled exception in the main thread. But why unhandled exceptions in a thread spawn for a System.Threading.Timer task produce this "do you want to open debugger" dialog in Windows?

Yes, you can always wrap the whole task in a try/catch-all block, but I find that odd.

Note: I tried a simple command line program, that has a task in a Timer object that throws an exception (after few seconds) - still it seems there is no way of stopping Windows from killing the process.

Comment: "Do you want to open the debugger?" (because this program is malfunctioning)... Seriously, deal with your exceptions, don't try to swallow them. It will bite you hard later. If you expect a certain exception to happen, write code to deal with it. That way, when the unexpected happens, you won't be left in the dark.

Comment: I tried to set a global exception handler, as you can in the JVM (http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/uncaught-java-thread-exceptions/240148320) but this does not work on windows. I bet I will have to get used to this in this platform.

Answer (score 1):

If your tread can continue working even after the exception then a global try catch wrap would be enough. The question is, is your thread able to continue after the exception? How vital is that exception for your thread? And if it is vital don't you want to know that happened?

if you do not know how the exception occurred and you do not want to wrap the hole code into a try catch you can use an UnhandledException handler to log the error in order to correct it in the future.

Here is an example in vb.net:

```
Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler


Sub MyHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
End Sub 'MyUnhandledExceptionEventHandler
```

Comment: Thanks @Reven but above does not work. It just adds a handler to the handler list so you can do some cleaning up. But the thread still causes the program to die. I bet the only option is to always wrap callbacks in try/catch blocks.